# Managing Forked that Will stay Close to the Original Project

Tags: git, project-management

I have a wordpress theme that I wrote. I originally wrote it for one website.

Now I am deploying it to a few different websites (about five). Each site is going to modify the code to suit its particular needs. I expect the divergences to be relatively minor, but significant enough that the five forks will be distinct projects.

In the future each of those five websites may have different administrators. For now, I am administering them all.

It doesn't make sense to try to generalize all the needs of each site and continue to work from one unified code base. This would be really cumbersome.

However, I often make "house-keeping" changes to the original code, and it would be nice for those changes to be able to push downstream without manually editing it in to each of the five forks each time.  Similarly, it would also be nice if they could push bug-fixes upstream to me.

Here is the solution I am considering trying. I'm sure I am not the first person to run into this problem, and I don't want to re-invent the wheel unnecessarily:

1. Give each site that wants to use the theme git-read access to the main code base.
2. Each site can then clone my repository, create their own branch, and do whatever changes they'd like in their branch.
3. If they want to pull updates from upstream, they can do a git pull and rebase their branch against main. This may require manual merges and becomes more difficult as the code-bases grow further apart, but assuming the differences they code in aren't drastic, this will be a relatively painless process.
4. If they want to suggest a bug fix to the main code base -- ??

Will this be a good solution? What problems might I run into? Is there a better solution to this (I'm assuming) common problem?

Answer (score 1):

> This may require manual merges and becomes more difficult as the code-bases grow further apart, but assuming the differences they code in aren't drastic

That is probably the main pain-point in this solution.

What I would do is to:

- make my commits small enough to identify if it is one specific for the local site, or one that needs to be contributed back to the main code base.
- dedicate a local branch dedicated for commits that need to be contributed back.

So once I have finished a series of commits (some specific to the local site, some for the common site), I would cherry-pick the ones for the common site to that dedicated branch.
And I would rebase, then merge that dedicated branch to the main code base branch.

That way, the branch that is working with the code base only includes commits that are relevant for said main code base.